# Hello world!!! Fibonacci distribution

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, hello-world, fibonacci

1. Your program should output exactly: `Hello world!!!` with or without linefeed after.
2. Your program should take no input.
3. Sourcecode character distribution must be correct according to:

   - The number of **numeric characters** (0-9) must be exactly one fibonacci sequence number.
   - The number of **other non-numeric characters** !(0-9) in the sourcecode must be exactly the fibonacci sequence number before the above fibonacci sequence number.

Four examples of valid character distribution in sourcecode:

- 13 numeric, 8 non-numeric characters.
- 34 numeric, 21 non-numeric characters.
- 55 numeric, 34 non-numeric characters.
- 89 numeric, 55 non-numeric characters.

This is code-golf, shortest code in bytes wins! Good luck!

Edit: As this question has constraints on the sourcecode size in combination with being code-golf the accepted answer (if more than one share the equal winning character length) will be the answer with most votes (and least character-count): 2014-03-01.

Comment: Thus, all solutions have a character count which is a fibonacci number.

Comment: @Howard Indeed. This is a very interesting problem.

Comment: [Here is a program to validate answers](http://ideone.com/K2BxjV) (paste the code into the input box.)

Comment: Is it even possible to do this in less than 55 characters? The required output has 14 chars, and I can't think of a language that can use numbers to output chars without using at least one character per char.

Comment: I regret I didn't put a constraint on the distribution for the non-numeric too, separating alpha-characters and symbols. Is it okay to update the rules now this late, rendering your answers invalid?

Comment: @Plarsen definitely not OK

Comment: Okay, I will not change the rules then :)

Comment: @Quincunx: It is possible.

Comment: @xfix it might be, but your solution doesn't achieve that

Comment: Questions without an objective primary winning criterion are off-topic, as they make it impossible to indisputably decide which entry should win. A codegolf challenge where the code length is forced to be a certain value lack such a criterion.

Comment: I added a criterion for who will win if more than one answer shares the same character count.

Comment: @Plarsen Why don't you change it and say: "write the smallest program you can" and change [tag:code-golf] to [tag:popularity-contest]?

Comment: What would have been even more interesting would be to specify that all characters had to be functional - that is, comments and non-essential code could not contribute to the character count.

Comment: I agree, @Iszi.  I threw answers in, in two languages because padding with comments made it easy.  However, while "no comments" could be construed as objective criteria, I think "non-essential code" could be seen as subjective. (It's usually easy to weave some numeric calculation or string manipulation into code which does *something* and, if cleverly woven, cannot be removed without fundamentally rewriting the answer.)

Comment: This question seems to have been left in a state where it contradicts itself about the winning criterion, and I am therefore voting to close it as off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contradicts itself about the winning criterion.

Comment: @pppery It doesn't contradict itself. It clearly states that [popularity-contest] is used as a tiebreaker.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Windows Command Prompt - <strike>34, 8</strike>, 5 chars, (2 below)

**These ones may or may not be breaking rule 2, but here it is anyway*

```
%~099
```

Name the file:

```
&start call echo Hello world!!!&exit -b .cmd
```

**Now lets corrupt the file-system a little - 2 chars (or less if you want)**

```
A1
```

Name the file (using your preferred unorthodox method):

```
"&start call echo Hello world!!!&exit&.cmd
```

*How does this work:*

Since cmd scripts are invoked with 'cmd.exe /C "%1" %*' the executed command will be:

```
cmd.exe /C "c:\PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT\"&start call echo Hello world!!!&exit&.cmd"
```

which will in the following order:

- Fail to execute "c:\PATH_TO_THE_SCRIPT\"
- Open a new shell printing Hello world!\n
- Exit the original shell

Comment: Wow! I think we had got a winner if the rules wasn't saying no input. +1 anyway for the outside-of-box thinking.

Comment: Code golf with Windows CMD... +1. Also, it is arguable that "no input" could have meant "no reading STDIN" :P

Comment: That's an interesting trick for other code golfs too… write the real code in the file name and use something like `eval $0` to execute it <rolleyes>

Comment: That's impossible!! 5 chars? Really interesting approach

Comment: In fact, I've just posted a **2 char** solution below.

Comment: Just for reference these types of answers are not allowed by [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/56656), however it predates the creation of the loophole [so us moderators will not be accepting flags to delete it right now](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9045/56656).

Answer (score 21):

## MySQL, 34

```
x'48656C6C6F20776F726C642121'||'!'
```

This is a MySQL expression that evaluates to `Hello world!!!`, assuming the `sql_mode` setting includes `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`. It contains exactly 21 digits and 13 non-digits.

Whether this qualifies as a valid entry, I leave it to the jury.

**Example**

```
mysql> select x'48656C6C6F20776F726C642121'||'!';
+------------------------------------+
| x'48656C6C6F20776F726C642121'||'!' |
+------------------------------------+
| Hello world!!!                     |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What the... CMD and SQL winning code golf??

Comment: The `select` and `;` are arguably part of the statement, but still a clever solution.

Comment: @primo they are, that's why I'm unsure whether this qualifies. But I thought I'd post it for hilarity ;-)

Answer (score 16):

## C64 BASIC, 55

[image]

For fun and nostalgia!

Answer (score 11):

#### GolfScript, 55 characters

```
[72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33 {.}2*]''+
```

Didn't find a way to have a 34 characters solution, thus I created this one.

Answer (score 10):

## Befunge 98 - 55

```
a"!!!dlrow olleH"ek,@1235813213455891442333776109871597
```

Decided to do it with a newline, since it doesn't cost anything. The numbers are the concatenated values of the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 8):

### Python 34-55

```
print "Hello world%s"%("!"*int(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820))
```

Yes. I waste them digits. What are you gonna do about it?

Comment: Who knew pi~3 would be so useful!

Comment: The question says 21 non-numeric plus 34 numeric, your answer is 34 non-numeric plus 21 numeric.

Comment: the "hello world" should be "Hello world"; that is capitalize the h.

Answer (score 7):

## Windows PowerShell (probably also Bash), 55

```
curl -L bit.ly/1b9q8ve?1=123581321345589144233377610987
```

You didn't say anything about network access, so here's a dirty solution. I've got a bit.ly URL with few enough letters on the second try. Unfortunately, It's still 21 non-digits, needing 34 digits to be used or wasted.

Comment: You know you can edit the bit.ly links right?

Comment: What do you mean, edit? Also, I wouldn't get this under 13 letters in any case.

Comment: You can hit the pencil next to "Copy" and edit the link. If you do, all the old versions will still work.

Comment: Shortened to 34! `curl 37.187.42.18/?hw=112358132134`

Answer (score 7):

## C (89 characters)

```
main() {
int i[0000000000000004]={1819043144,1870078063,560229490,2566922529};
puts(i);
}
```

While the above is valid, unfortunately, my efforts to compact it with the following program doesn't meet the spec. I feel like it's worth looking at and maybe someone else can shorten it a bit though (64 characters, 37 numerals, 27 non-numerals).  To compile it, you'll have to use clang and with `-fms-extensions`.

```
main(){puts((__int128[]){671944380693508453879479574226248i8});}
```

Comment: [Compound literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), is the name for what you're looking for. I'm trying to use them to get this down to 21 characters now!

Comment: The lowest non-numeric count I can reach is 26, by making `i` global (omitting `int`). Using `long` can save commas, but costs more. 21 is very far.

Comment: Yeah, it's a lot of wasted space.  Using that little trick, I can get it to `main(){puts((int[]){1819043144,1870078063,560229490,8481});}` but that's still 60 characters.  If I could eliminate just a few more...  Edit: wow, so globals don't have to have a declaration?  Who knew?

Comment: @vmrob, globals have to have a declaration. But the type defaults to `int`, so `a;` is equivalent to `int a;`.

Comment: @ugoren I knew that they had to have a declaration, I just didn't realize it defaulted to int!

Answer (score 6):

## sh, 55

```
echo Hello world!!! #1234567890123456789012345678901234
```

Answer (score 6):

## Korn Shell, 21

```
echo $0
#123456789012
```

The script must be called "Hello world!!!" :)

Answer (score 5):

### Python

```
print'092020090920200948656c6c6f20776f726c642121212009200909200920'.decode('hex').strip()
```

digits : 55
non digits: 34

Comment: Note there are no comments in the solution. only code.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP (55 bytes)

This program uses binary (wow, it's the third time I reuse the same trick). 21 non-numeric characters, 34 numeric characters. No letters, because letters are boring.

### `xxd`

```
0000000: 3c3f 3d7e b79a 9393 90df 8890 8d93 9bde  <?=~............
0000010: dede f53b 2331 3233 3435 3637 3839 3031  ...;#12345678901
0000020: 3233 3435 3637 3839 3031 3233 3435 3637  2345678901234567
0000030: 3839 3031 3233 34                        8901234
```

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm almost sure I read "before or after". Oh well, let me fix it then.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica 55

```
"Hello World!!!"(34+21!)/000000000051090942171709440034
```

Output

```
Hello World!!!
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting) (34 characters)

```
丟0000000000긒괡뉆롲닷댠닶롬뉔밈0000000000併0反
```

Unfortunately Sclipting doesn’t use any ASCII characters at all, so I have to pad the program with 21 useless number characters :(

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 2 chars

Very well, in the unlikely case Robert's answer is not disqualified, here's mine:

```
$0
```

Name the file `echo Hello world!!!` and execute with `sh`.

Comment: Just for reference these types of answers are not allowed by [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/56656), however it predates the creation of the loophole [so us moderators will not be accepting flags to delete it right now](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9045/56656).

Comment: @GrainGhost it was a tongue in cheek answer anyways! But it goes to show how much side channels matter sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 8+13=21 bytes

```
kh6⁽NV33C3ẋ#123456789
```

kh6⁽NV = Hello world

33C = ASCII 33 to !

3ẋ = repeat top of stack three times

(Note that 33C3ẋ is one non numeric less than literal !!! would be)

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCJraDbigb1OVjMzQzPhuosjMTIzNDU2Nzg5IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I can’t seem to get the string with only 5 non-numeric chars

Answer (score 2):

### Forth or Ruby, 55

(34 numeric + 21 non-numeric)

### Forth

```
." Hello world!!!" \ 3141592653589793238462643383279502
```

### Ruby

```
puts"Hello world!!!"#3141592653589793238462643383279502
```

Using comments to pad feels dirty, but those are valid answers.

Answer (score 2):

## J (55 characters)

(34 numeric + 21 non-numeric)

```
(72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100{a.), 3#33{a.
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 55 bytes

```
14↑'Hello world!!!!!!!11111111111111111111111111111111'
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 233 Bytes

233 Characters
144 Numeric
89 Non-Numeric Characters

```
/*I suck at CodeGolf!!!*/new List<int>{0072,00101,000108,000108,000111,0000032,00000119,00000111,0000000000114,0000000000108,00000000000000100,00000000000000033,00000000000000033,00000000000000033}.ForEach(c=>Console.Write((char)c));
```

Outputs:

```
Hello world!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 55 bytes

```
"aaaaaaa1234567890123456789012345678901234"`HÁM WŽld!!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XykRAgyNjE1MzcwtLA1wsZQSPA43@iqEH@rLSVFUVPz/HwA)

It is basically a simple hello world with some rubbish at the beginning that is ignored but makes the code satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Numeric: 34 bytes + Non-numeric: 21 bytes = 55 bytes.

- Filename: `Hello world!!!.pxxxxx1234567890123456789012345678901234`
- Content: empty

The boring answer. The stupid latter part is nothing but a garbage.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V@I4FP/fTxE6lSa0pQ2gIrUqg67DrjLqOB5HQE9pi4K1sLQoWtivPnuTFoEyO2c9R5v87jP3kYdPwePPT59sy7K3bbez0y3sFqhldd2iZZeLdrdECzq1t8r6jrtd6BY2AjdEqjs2xs9W8IR0vVAw3MlwMArRae2@enpq1gwcvg1d9OCG9sDvZrN8Zg@eny3fIfua475o/tjzUGE/S7PZRPi8evXFFESc8CF1OFfASUSM2EeuzOKBOhPmZr836jf3366OzIKuF@fg@ddv9ZvTH/e1r5eXx7UrkxpNJIjR5@q3L/fXx5ff6l8bFfltJiATvaF2NstXNUDDQdCbxDP5cyxy@x8S7vPYs0IXBY@cfzAMYfg6GDnB0OuF2azl9awAqQ9IEiMqC@KhMJNMiX2lbLbx/fS0dnZkVrgNzOw5RvDY64YGHyPGlwCu/ThA4ifCLFNmOQOGCgPP2c9C6F8sDwkZ1LW8wBWm02UaV82lJ9PAdZAUaBPtTTMC@POuSVzhO2ozIc4FPHNRGxM8gCRUfaS@hGM6DUdIrQWo1dTV3TaSmi0/15amDyN3iPKxcu2utC1qUaVqiB2jYWgtn8/PwdxdPt/yNc3oVI1ZPG3eMT2UFkRtqBnhMljW1zFKqagNUuDO7jpGKUj7acbyOkb1LVHrpRmL69gu8N2nMbBsp7DtnXWMUhAO0usrrmOUgosvacbtdYzqELFu2m19HaM6RMxN@7i7jlFaErVR2nRhHaMUpF/TjDvrGOwXIhRairG8jtEC@PiWZtxdx2gB/HlPJ0H/BQbuWOlFb61jlEJsw7Tl0jpGdXDnOR3vnXWM6uCOkzZdXsdKkH45jYGLagorAl8mjYHXYhoDZzYZNpOm2LaS7cIhSVPyftWiE9aUE8OB/jth0i2cb5EWbvnsbz7XIqLWKrYKLaoBV6Dlc9Ctk9X@rniGmIm05uvk7d1y2lomahgdDxTOjDdodg1phta8S6isxEUNOdqKDtVHUmK@eXeotMEueICb8RBcKBwi5sJjwhPjKJ8DEvcstg7rGXI3RU1haAdcgBRHMMtEAYyq2tDoXAAasymHoOCD0flgdLSjOeMK25ySxKEyMsQoNneImGrY4jg3qs6RsMpDK2YaQGn5TaS@t3MO0xaOlhBYEo9PO16sxkkWsA15TuPFWbHUDLytXHyozHPfwovUnpvE4wtE5qgKcZkkyeWRXcQtjs9Joon/xq7EniRZ/5WghOZHx1JCtF4Xe1bH9UxTaFGBRHwluDkc@L17O3jpuqPwWc6Im2qbcbcoJob2EPOwemxFVGnNGOkct2hCs5ZdCsYdLLCECAqTPoCxUBEOBYWbJbPE4Cr/75iPRK0zcq0nPoG8VbHgDQZD5A9C9GyF9mPPfxCAVZovV8ZE62BKGL/Kx2o8yfCJzscijP9Oxpt8DDzQh7wHpe5glIQJnDEMEknGR4NKM4mQn380qmfHpvTF9bwBgruD52Qymfxwwn5ooVja2t4p7@r/NZI2al8bV8eNK1OSNvBw1PPDLhz5XKkQn9gOgnhPX22k2hu/YvgdnaMEbgM/g5FtSp@PT@qNCDIvB67rkGAEtzTMh7Pu2LfD3sBH5/iIRN@aT8pfmLTNIwOGbVle0I8xiUZuOB75KCMDz4Ly54IC@D5dUP5aUJi6BeFqhcBMqnSJfIMvSXRpAhd3Q1WNhPlywTPGNRLxdaPaAj3Bl8rth264hXo9393XD0S9oi459iU2IFKDV98dL20ZilAQyAqEYmjd/HdmfuybS7ar@Gzu0dlUgHKB@LObbi9ES6aHsPTXx57n4gyElAyWIwmTCMDpdIxvgLYg@LiuXCtHikdYFrlgdG0Cj@GZnus/hI/4mhisaOtwXa7vmZ5BxhgfmbCWIBzha6Uuywol5B@Br0s4OJJL5Uppi8wWRnpg/RyfrBi@x2dKTblVfpDozBTy9xXUgK6zkOPavWe4vsJi3Qd3BN/hOBSMmgnixi34wHxhfQPulnb2atlsbW@rTHgfG4DV/hHuSs3iVluELejWLJXUWiIctzqw4HIsRksQkJppFgskilngZRH2/LE7YxFnrLW9Uhl49rd2CINi4wuzsWbyw8Q/CKqppbLBsmec49vcj6W12vPon@OrlSAEc8LNcrJeICd95ZpEdVPnFvsmr2MIf5@VrdJX1bZ5zRLFZvU2ByEPbT7vt5dCP1qYhohi3p8kx2pgyeDromnWvZngC4XbykA7sghnYHbBS@TavNhjvIns9ULo7bdC@78Wev9wg0lxN9QVV8L5Yh6hd80V0jOQnqBYEDy8zjGjLxE72IKAxiX@J6vwc2wdgLhssUhUbpKIGIsdI2dStZDD1p5Ocixn8F0K6t9pff2kY26SxeJ@ziNQMWBGyG/CuZOHahQq6NYdwTWs99ILQI3ACoUlxTro73sH/U2v4m32K3ys8THkaBbvsOCZqbehHOCtuLap20SQFs51IRIrXMl5IEzX326/ebqZ8ZkXXzTgHgdnIHtCqyP/iU7tMYwcCUlI7RbmhyPci85xlrA35JI7Li/m@NCNoHB5QT/JsiHL/T3MNmFWtBDyOPz9ZAoDYvx6GWy5juu58MyGPEMrJNsTNIgs1/dAXKZxS/CTps41yhT6JN705XjenkkGO6nY/xfgJmYj/j@IMeuQwTN7UQM4WgMXMXRKSG2UVhimUzyE1311gIY9R3HD3rOrDO3hWHkJ3g3HCl2ynIPS79/PKLR6HtyOS0sBZjf0qMxuSfwuJk2t1yfQhSxTLdDSTqlc3C6VkRRZsinqs@PGUXJqWHCxEDb@d/4TrUl02EeABMCBL3CSJOpwxYMfAQVxerCwORAUUSfSdGKNHiAG9QlKMjdBGz//BQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.11, 34+21=55 bytes

Boring answer, uses comments to store extra junk.

```
print("Hello world!!!")#abcdef12345678901234567890123456
```

Answer (score -1):

### Windows Batch

```
echo Hello World!!!::0123456789012345678901234567890123
```

Comment: Wow. This is so much different from my sh solution.