# Fibonacci distribution validator

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, fibonacci

> **Related:** [Hello world!!! Fibonacci distribution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/hello-world-fibonacci-distribution)

Create a program that returns True if a given input meets the following specifications, and False otherwise:

- The count of numeric characters (0-9) in the input matches a Fibonacci number.
- The count of non-numeric characters !(0-9) in the input matches the Fibonacci number immediately preceding the count of numeric characters.

Additional Rules:

- Your program must use the proper Fibonacci sequence, per OEIS - that is, the Fibonacci sequence must start with `0, 1, 1, 2, ...`
- If the numerics or non-numerics count is 1, the following must occur:

  - Numerics 1: Non-numeric count of 0 *or* 1 should be handled as True - all others False.
  - Non-Numerics 1: Numerics count of 1 *or* 2 should be handled as True - all others False.
- Input may be taken however you like, but the program must be capable of handling any arbitrary text.
- True/False are not case-sensitive, and can be substituted with 1/0 or T/F.
- You may only hard-code up to two Fibonacci numbers.
- Output may *only* be True/False or 1/0 or T/F. Any additional text or visible errors generated is unacceptable.

Comment: give some example IO

Comment: @Subhanker See the linked question for some example True cases.

Comment: Relevant wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Recognizing_Fibonacci_numbers

Comment: is T/F or T/nil acceptable as well?

Comment: Am I right that we can either output or return?

Comment: @Quincunx I interpret it as "output". I believe a return value is acceptable.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm honestly not sure which language to use right now, so I'd like to keep my options open. I interpret the same as you.

Comment: @Quincrux Output preferably, but since there's already some answers I won't modify the challenge.

Comment: @JanDvorak T/F is okay, but I wouldn't be too keen to accept T/nil.

Comment: @Iszi T/nil is the standard representation of booleans in Lisp. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: "You may only hard-code up to two Fibonacci numbers." - you're changing this rule too often (even one invalidating change counts as too often). Why not drop it entirely?

Comment: @JanDvorak That seems to be a rather unique case I'd rather not mess with re-writing a rule (again) for. Sorry. As it is, I've added a fair bit since the start of this challenge already. I'd rather not edit it any more if I can get away with it. I thought this was going to be relatively simple, but perhaps it could have used some time in the Sandbox (AKA: Black Hole of My Ideas).

Comment: @JanDvorak The original rule was to not hard-code Fibonacci numbers at all, which is a rather general statement of the rule's intent. However, some people (yourself included) took it a bit too literally and started writing disclaimers like "well, I had to hard-code a couple..." into their answers. I modified it to allow for the first two, because those are the bare essentials needed to start generation of the sequence. Then someone (oh, that was you again) requested a generalization of the rule to allow for the second and third numbers instead...

Comment: ...I'm done editing that rule. It's now strict enough to serve its purpose while still being just permissive enough to allow programs to be functional - which is how I like my rules to be in general anyway.

Comment: You've still invalidated the first revision of my javascript solution. You might just say "you may not hard code the entire fibonacci sequence", but that's hardly beneficial because such sequence would be longer than the generator.

Comment: @JanDvorak Your current revision is shorter, and fits the current version of the anti-hard-coding rule. I fail to understand why *you* would complain about *that* particular rule at this point.

Comment: Ugh, you changed the challenge. Now you say that the fibonacci sequence starts at 0 and give specific cases for 0. The other question that you linked to forbids 0, so I assumed the same.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, <del>92 88</del> 86 characters

```
t=prompt()
for(b=c=1;c<t[l='length'];c=a+b)a=b,b=c
alert(c==t[l]&b==t.match(/\d/g)[l])
```

I hope you don't mind I've hard-coded the the first three Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Does it handle multiple lines of text?

Comment: @Quincunx Chrome lets you copy/paste but not type newlines into the prompt input; haven't tested firefox.

Comment: Guess I learn something new every day.

Comment: According to OEIS, the first three Fibonacci numbers are 0, 1, 1. In any case, you should only need to hard-code the first two - why did you do three?

Comment: @Iszi you are right - `a` didn't need initialisation. As for why do I start at 1,2,3 - the poster of the initial challenge didn't accept `1` as immediately preceding `1`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ah. Well, while the two are related this is indeed a separate challenge. I prefer to go by more proper definitions when dealing with a defined number series.

Comment: @Iszi do you mind if I hard-code the second and third fibonacci number instead?

Comment: So long as your program can also answer True for the case where the input is a single digit... which brings me to an interesting case I forgot to consider. If your numerics count is 1, then I suppose the program should output True if you have zero non-numerics *or* 1 non-numeric in the input.

Comment: @Iszi but, what about the case I have 1 non-numeric (-1st fibonacci number), 0 numeric (0th fibonacci number) and 1 total (1st fibonacci number) characters?

Comment: @JanDvorak Total characters is not a consideration for this program. Only the counts for numeric and non-numeric characters are of any concern. I'll clarify the ones situation in an edit shortly.

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript, 36

```
:?1 2{.@+.?,<}do?,=@{.48<\58<^},,@=*
```

Explanation:

- `:?` stores the input into `?`.
- `1 2{.@+.?,<}do` computes the last two fibonacci numbers until it hits the input length. The block reads: "duplicate the top, rotate the third value to the top, add them, duplicate the top, get the input, get its length, compare".
- `?,=` compares the last computed fibonacci number to the input length.
- `@` brings the input to the top
- `{.48<\58<^},` filters out only digits. The block reads "is the ASCII value below 48 XOR below 58?"
- `,@=` compares the filtered string length to the lower fibonacci number (count of digits)
- `*` merges the two comparisons to provide a single boolean value.

Live demo: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIvMDU5OiIKOj8xIDJ7LkArLj8sPH1kbz8sPUB7LjQ4PFw1ODxefSwsQD0q

Answer (score 3):

## Python - <s>128</s> 125

```
import re
def v(s):
 l=len(re.sub("\d","",s));L=len(s)-l;a,b=1,2
 while a<L:
    if a==l and b==L:
     print 1;return
    b,a=a+b,b
 print 0
```

Really hope there is no problem with hardcoding the first few fibonacci numbers

Comment: Isn't there... too much whitespace?

Comment: @JanDvorak those four spaces were all tabs, so they were counted as 1 char per four spaces. I could alternate tabs and spaces, doing that now.

Comment: Looks like I should have been a bit more clear about hard-coding the numbers. Of course you'll need to prime the sequence, but you should only need the first two to do it.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 105 characters

Script file name is passed to the program through the command line

```
import sys
a=[0]*2
for b in open(sys.argv[1]).read():a['/'<b<':']+=1
a,b=a
while a>0:a,b=b-a,a
print(b==1)
```

### 87 characters

Script must be written in file with name `s`

```
a=[0]*2
for b in open('s').read():a['/'<b<':']+=1
a,b=a
while a>0:a,b=b-a,a
print(b==1)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
ḟ,fɗØDẈẇ⁸LŻÆḞ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvk6aSenH57h8nBXx8Nd7Y8ad/gc3X247eGOeYeW/D/c/qhpzdFJD3fO@P8/motTyVBJB0RWgKkKCzMIrW5iYWZq5gyEbkYG5uZmbuZGQLaJkaGRoXpNjbqiOlhZYpKhkTGQBTLACGoO1CAICZEGKUyGMGMB)

### How it works

```
ḟ,fɗØDẈẇ⁸LŻÆḞ¤ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
    ØD         - Yield "0123456789"; D
   ɗ           - Group the previous three atoms together as a dyad, f(S, D):
ḟ              -   Remove digits from S
  f            -   Remove non-digits from S
 ,             -   Pair these two
      Ẉ        - Lengths of each in the pair; [a, b]
             ¤ - Create a nilad:
        ⁸      -   Yield S
         L     -   Take its length, L
          Ż    -   [0, 1, 2, ..., L]
           ÆḞ  -   nth Fibonacci number for each
       ẇ       - Sublist exists?
                 This returns 1 if the left argument ([a, b]) is a contiguous sublist
                 of the right argument (the list of Fib numbers), i.e.
                 a and b are both Fibonacci numbers, and a immediately precedes b
```

Comment: It's funny how I've saved a byte by changing the first portion of my program to what you had in your first iteration, yet you saved a byte by changing the first portion of your program to what I had in my first iteration. xD

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well, different builtins are shorter/better in different languages :P

Comment: Ik, ik. It's just funny how we've basically swapped the implementation of our first parts to both save a byte in our languages. ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 92

```pl
$_=join"",<>;@_=1;$d=s/\d//g;push@_,$t=$_[-1]+$_[-2]while$t<$d;print$t==$d&$_[-2]==y///c?1:0
```

Usage:

```bash
cat fib-test 
print "Hello world%s"%("!"*int(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820))

perl -e '$_=join"",<>;@_=1;$d=s/\d//g;push@_,$t=$_[-1]+$_[-2]while$t<$d;print$t==$d&$_[-2]==y///c?1:0' fib-test
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java - <s>147</s> 145

```
boolean v(String s){int l=s.replaceAll("\\d","").length(),L=s.length()-l,a=1,b=2,c;while(a<L){if(a==l&&b==L)return 0<1;c=b;b+=a;a=c;}return 0>1;}
```

I'd say this is not bad for Java.

**Edit**: Thanks to Chris Hayes for [suggesting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18887/fibonacci-distribution-validator/18892?noredirect=1#comment37072_18892) `0>1` for false and `0<1` for true.

Comment: As long as we're using `1==0` to save on characters, you could use `0<1` in place of `true`, and `0>1` for `false`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
d1Ý¢¤ÅFs.kd
```

-3 bytes by taking inspiration from [*@cairdCoinheringaahing*'s initial Jelly program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/214232/1)
-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*

Input as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xfDw3EOLDi053OpWrJed8v9/tFKFko6SOhCbALEFEJsBsSmUdkaj3YDYCIgNgNgcimHi5lA5ZPUmUDFDJBpkVw0Ug9iKYDoWAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXw/xTDw3MPLTq05HCrW7Fedsp/nf/RSkZKOkqGFUCiwsIMRKqbWJiZmjkDoZuRgbm5mZu5EZBtYmRoZKheU6OuqA5UlJhkaGSspKOgBNILMQBsAgiDZYAqkiEMpVgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
d            # Check for each character in the (implicit) input-list if it's a
             # non-negative (>=0) integer (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
 1Ý          # Push the list [0,1]
   ¢         # Count them in the list of truthy/falsey results
    ¤        # Push the last count, without popping the pair itself
     ÅF      # Pop and push a list of Fibonacci numbers <= this count
       s     # Swap so the pair is at the top of the stack
        .k   # Get the index of the pair (as sublist) in the Fibonacci list
             # (or -1 if this pair isn't a sublist)
          d  # Check that this index is non-negative (>=0), thus that it was found
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Unfortunately the Fibonacci sequence contains two `1`s, otherwise we could have saved two bytes by changing `s.kd` to `sÅ¿` (check whether it ends with the pair), [which fails for single-digit inputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXw/xTDw3MPLTq05HCrW/Hh1kP7/@v8j1YyUtJRMqwAEhUWZiBS3cTCzNTMGQjdjAzMzc3czI2AbBMjQyND9ZoadUV1oKLEJEMjYyUdBSWQXogBYBNAGCwDVJEMYsQCAA).

Comment: You've still got the 15-byter as your code underneath the header. Also, very nice! 05AB1E's `ÅF` for sure gives it an advantage over Jelly here

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Woops, forgot to replace the code indeed. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You can replace `ü2` with `Œ` (sublists) for -1. And i think `d1Ý¢¤ÅFs.kd` works as a more efficient 11-byter.

Comment: @ovs Ah, the `ü2` to `Œ` is indeed an obvious one. As for the second, I didn't even knew the `.k` worked that way. I thought it was to get the index of a list in a list of lists, but apparently it also works to get the index of a list (as sublist) in a flattened list. TIL, and thanks for the -1.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 34 chars/bytes*

```
{n←+/⍵∘.=⍞∊⎕D⋄n≡+\∘⌽⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}⍵}⍳2
```

Expects the input string on standard input and prints either 0 or 1 as required. `⎕IO` must be set to 0 (the default is implementation-dependent.)

**Ungolfed**

```
s←⍞                ⍝ read input string
d←s∊⎕D             ⍝ vector with 1 for each digit, 0 for each non-digit in s
n←+/0 1∘.=d        ⍝ 2-vector with number of non-digits and number of digits in s
f←+\∘⌽             ⍝ a function that computes a fibonacci step (f 2 3 → 3 5)
t←f⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}0 1   ⍝ apply f repeatedly, starting with 0 1, until we get two fibonacci
                   ⍝   terms whose sum is ≥ the length of the input string (sum of n)
n≡t                ⍝ return 1 if the fibonacci terms match the no. of digits and non-digits
```

**Examples**

```
      {n←+/⍵∘.=⍞∊⎕D⋄n≡+\∘⌽⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}⍵}⍳2
%~n01234
1
      {n←+/⍵∘.=⍞∊⎕D⋄n≡+\∘⌽⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}⍵}⍳2
x'48656C6C6F20776F726C642121'||'!'
1
      {n←+/⍵∘.=⍞∊⎕D⋄n≡+\∘⌽⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}⍵}⍳2
[72 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100 33 {.}2*]''+
1
      {n←+/⍵∘.=⍞∊⎕D⋄n≡+\∘⌽⍣{≥/+/⊃⍺n}⍵}⍳2
What?12345
0
```

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>23</s> <s>21</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte, then -2 more bytes, thanks to Razetime*

```
€↑→L¹İfe#€ṁsŀ9¹L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmkdtEx@1TfI5tPPIhrRUZaDAw52NxUcbLA/t9Pn//7@SoZGxiWliUnJKqpm5hRIA)

```
€↑→L¹İfe#€ṁsŀ9¹L
€                       # index of argument in list, if found, otherwise 0,
 ↑                      # list: the first n elements
  →L¹                   # n = length of input +1
     İf                 # of the list of fibonacci numbers
       e                # argument: 2-element list
        #               # 1. number of elements in input that are
         €    ¹         # present in list of
          ṁsŀ9          # string from 0 to 9
               L        # 2. length of input
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmkdtE/MftU3yObTzyIa01HxloNDDnY3FRxssD@30@f//v5KhkbGJaWJSckqqmbmFEgA "Husk – Try It Online") by changing `'0'9`

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  ```'0'9``` did seem very clunky!

Comment: Does removing the compositions work correctly? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmkdtEx@1TfI5tPPIhrRUZaDAw52NxUcbLA/t9Pn//7@SoZGxiWliUnJKqpm5hRIA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime Indeed, it seems to work fine.  Thanks!  I'm surprised it works, but I guess that (by luck in this case) the argument types don't allow ambiguous interpretation...

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>46</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 32 bytes

- -12 bytes from golfing, -2 from @ngn's improvements

```
{~^(|+\)\[#x;|!2]?+/'~:\~"0:"'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw9zN9ugjAUBvB7ngLrkmr8U9o5aNqLXSzxJYDFUkAbkW60LjUizz7mrDk3vy/nfKdm1+Fz1i+yeZZOHe8nJH9fIDiwbAARA9DdgsCy60t6GTpWh2Ho+E4f+WxXC9Vwxy+8m+e3wKZLQADH+SiAnZej8ZNwQ+O3+GOcLYmSJN4mZPSGYIJh38MJ9JeiwOTVB8Cj/5/kKeceXAIv4O6V6NGXPgUoOFj7ZRhCUpfVXjf12lghj5WTB9Huq7XUJ/R9roxVujUIU0oTVKtCt0JKtSqVsZ0qzn/b1Y9oVCms7tAv+ntacQ==)

- `~"0:"'x` determine which characters in the input are digits
- `+/'~:\` count the number of digits and non-digits
- `~^(...)[...]?` determine if the above is in...

  - `(|+\)\[#x;|!2]` the pairs of fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 85

```
d=-(n=(i=$<.read).gsub(/\d/,'').size)+i.size
a=b=1;while b<d;b=a+a=b end;p b==d&&a==n
```

Takes input either on `STDIN` or as a filename argument.

Output is either `"true"` or `"false"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Êô@MgXÃã de[\D\d]£èX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=yvRATWdYw%2bMgZGVbXERcZF2j6Fg&input=WwoiMSIKIjF4IgoieDg2IgoieCc0ODY1NkM2QzZGMjA3NzZGNzI2QzY0MjEyMSd8fCchJyIKImFiMTIzIgoiMTIiCiIxeHgiCiJ4IgoieDEyMyIKImFiYzEyMyIKXS1tUg) (Test cases appropriated from [caird](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing))