# Count digits in a string, check if there its a fibonnaci number

Tags: code-golf, metagolf

- There's a [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/hello-world-fibonacci-distribution) with a comment with some code thats far too long.
- For a site that has counting fetish, this code just seems so wrong.
- Solve this meta-riddle, and explain it with a rhyme.
- Winner is the shortest code in a fortnights time.

The challenge:

1. Open a file as input.
2. Count and output the number of digits `(0,1,...9)` and non-digits (everything else).
3. If the number of digits and non-digits are consecutive fibonnacci numbers, with the number of digits is fibonnacci number `f(n)` and the number of non-digits is `f(n-1)`  the file is "valid", otherwise it is "Invalid"
4. Output this information as exactly as shown below.

Example 1:

```
Digits: 34 Nondigits: 21
Valid program
```

Example 2:

```
Digits: 33 Nondigits: 21
Invalid program
```

Comment: You may want to clarify the *order* of the consecutive Fibonacci numbers in Rule 3. It is currently a bit ambiguous and possibly opposite to [the other question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18812/hello-world-fibonacci-distribution).

Comment: Also, your examples are contrary to each other: 34 & 21 should not be both valid and invalid. Probably a typo.

Comment: looks good now! :-)

Comment: I see you like my validator. Interesting how my code is forked 5 times...

Comment: @Quincunx Completely a duplicate! Sorry about that folks!

Comment: Ouch, that rule about explaining in rhyme; it hurt my brain more than any program I wrote here.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 151

```
d=[0,0];$<.read.chars{|c|d[c>?/&&c<?:?0:1]+=1};puts"Digits: %d Nondigits: %d"%d
a=b=1;while b<d[0];b=a+a=b end;print ([b,a]==d)??V:"Inv","alid program"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java - 334

```
import java.nio.*;public class a{public static void main(String[]i)throws Exception{String s=new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(i[0])));int l=s.replaceAll("\\d","").length(),L=s.length()-l,a=1,b=2,c,d=0;while(a<L){if(a==l&&b==L)d=1;c=b;b+=a;a=c;}System.out.printf("Digits: %s Nondigits: %s\n%salid Program",L,l,d==0?"Inv":"V");}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] i) throws Exception {
        String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(i[0])));
        int l = s.replaceAll("\\d", "").length(), L = s.length() - l, a = 1, b = 2, c, d = 0;
        while (a < L) {
            if (a == l && b == L) {
                d = 1;
            }
            c = b;
            b += a;
            a = c;
        }
        System.out.printf("Digits: %s Nondigits: %s\n%salid Program", L, l, d == 0 ? "Inv" : "V");
    }
}
```

Explanation:

> Reads the input from the file
>
> supplied by command line
>
> Puts the contents in a String
>
> oh no! I'm thinking of quines.
>
> Regex swaps digits of that thing
>
> for the one and only empty String.
>
> Then by `String#length()` I find
>
> the charcount nondigit, yes that kind.
>
> From the length of the first String
>
> I subtract the charcount nondigit thing
>
> to find the char digits count.
>
> Next I sweep it all under the rug
>
> so I can say "Help I'm a bug!".
>
> Then I retrieve it - please have patience.
>
> Now the first terms of the Fibonacci sequence
>
> used to find the rest of the numbers.
>
> What to rhyme with? I'll just use "others".
>
> And when small num is greater than non-digits
>
> I know if it's true, so wait a minute.
>
> Uses `printf` to format output.
>
> `"alid Program"` at the start puts
>
> `"Inv"` or `"V"` according to the answer
>
> Before is the counts, not one thing fancier
>
> Thank you for lis'ning to this tale
>
> Of the program that validates according to your rules

---

Whew, it was hard to write that.

I decided to assume the input is from the command line, in the form of a String. Please correct me, because if I can simply take a `File` as input, I can shorten this by a few chars. Also, I'd like to know if a method is okay.

Answer (score 0):

### Bash, 244

```
f=`cat $1`&&d=`sed 's/[0-9]*//g' $1`&&echo Digits: ${#d} Nondigits: $[${#f}-${#d}]]
a=1&&b=1&&while [ $b -lt ${#d} ];do z=$b&&b=$[a+b]&&a=$z;done&&if [ $b -eq ${#d} -a $a -eq $[${#f}-${#d}] ];then echo Valid program;else echo Invalid program;fi
```

call using `./script filename`.

I'm not particularly good with bash and I'm sure there are a few ways to get this smaller.